# Linq Select why am I getting a result?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am getting a very strange result with my linq query that I don't understand:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Imagine that I have a `ICollection<Person>` with one entry and that person is having a Address `null`

When I do the following linq statement:

```
var test = person.Select(x => x.Address).ToList();
```

the `test` variable is a List with 1 entry which is `null`.

- Why exactly do I get one `null` entry instead of an empty list?
- What would I have to change to get an empty list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) you get one entry, because [_select_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) not filter collection, and just map one collection to another, 2) if you need filter list you should use [_where_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Why exactly do I get one null entry instead of an empty list?*

Because  `Select is a projection` and it will  give just the result of adress so null

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
```

*What would I have to change to get an empty list?*

```
 var test = person.Where(x => x.Address != null).Select(x => x.Address).ToList();
```

or in `LINQ Query Expression`

```
var t = from p in person
                where p.Adresse != null
                select p.Adresse;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `where` statement to limit the results so that it contains only persons for which address is not null:

```
var test = person.Where(x => x.Address != null).Select(x => x.Address).ToList();
```

If you don't do this, your results are not filtered and you just get back a projection of all elements in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is just a set of specialized iterations.

At the end of the day, your call to `Select` extension method is something like this:

```
foreach(Person person in persons)
{
    // This is equivalent to person => person.Address
    yield return person.Address;
}
```

...and this is why you're getting a collection of strings where there's a single `null` ítem.

In the other hand, if you want to filter the sequence so you won't get a collection with `null` references, what would you do without LINQ? Maybe something like this:

```
foreach(Person person in persons)
{
    if(person.Address != null)
        yield return person.Address;
}
```

...And in LINQ world, this is a `Where`, then a `Select`:

```
persons.Where(person => person.Address != null).Select(person => person.Address);
```